# Cannot load sidepanel.jelly in Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im getting the next error when I try to load "sidepanel.jelly" in my Jenkins plugin action jelly file.

`javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Tecnoy/Escritorio/vats_eclipse/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/vats/VatsBuildAction/index.jelly:4:42: <st:include> No page found 'sidepanel.jelly' for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.vats.VatsBuildAction
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:717)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:390)
...
Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Tecnoy/Escritorio/vats_eclipse/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/vats/VatsBuildAction/index.jelly:4:42: <st:include> No page found 'sidepanel.jelly' for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.vats.VatsBuildAction
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
...`

My jelly file has the following lines

`<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson">
    <l:layout norefresh="true">
    <st:include page="sidepanel.jelly" />
    <l:main-panel>
        <h1>Vats Summary:</h1>
        <div id="canvas-holder">
            <p><canvas id="chart-area" width="300" height="300"/></p>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${resURL}/plugin/vats/scripts/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
...
    </script>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </l:main-panel>
  </l:layout>
</j:jelly>`

Any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `<l:main-panel>` tag and the the `<l:layout norefresh="true">`tag to the index.jelly file.

And include the side panel:

- Pass the the build to Action (through a parameter of the constructor)

  - The build can be retrieved out of the parameters of the perform method which is inherited from the BuildStepCompatibilityLayer class (by Extending Publisher).
- Create a getBuild() method in the Action class
- Add the `<st:include it="${it.build}" page="sidepanel.jelly" />` tag with the build

**Jelly Example (index.jelly):**

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:i="jelly:fmt" xmlns:p="/lib/hudson/project">
    <l:layout norefresh="true">
        <st:include it="${it.build}" page="sidepanel.jelly" />
        <l:main-panel>
            <f:validateButton title="${%Restart Jenkins}" progress="${%Restarting...}" method="JksRestart" with="" />
        </l:main-panel>
    </l:layout>
</j:jelly>
```

**Java Action class example:**

```
package tryPublisher.tryPublisher;

import hudson.model.Action;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;


public class ExampleAction implements Action {
    AbstractBuild<?,?> build;

    public ExampleAction(AbstractBuild<?,?> build) {
        this.build = build;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIconFileName() {
        return "/plugin/action.png";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "ExampleAction";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUrlName() {
        return "ExampleActionUrl";
    }

    public AbstractBuild<?,?> getBuild() {
        return this.build;
    }
}
```

**Java Publisher class example:**

```
package tryPublisher.tryPublisher;

import java.io.IOException;

import hudson.Launcher;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.BuildListener;
import hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor;
import hudson.tasks.Publisher;

public class ExamplePublisher extends Publisher {

    @Override
    public BuildStepMonitor getRequiredMonitorService() {
        return BuildStepMonitor.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher,
            BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        build.getActions().add(new ExampleAction(build));

        return true;
    }

}
```

The .jelly file has to be in the right resources map of the plugin project. In a map with the same name as the name of the Java class implementing Action. The name of the .jelly is important also.